# Get specific links from the list

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to print the text of the SECOND  tag in the first 5 "groupings" and pick the first in the second five. How would I do this?

https://www.carehome.co.uk/care_search_results.cfm/searchunitary/Tower-Hamlets

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

#grabspage and parses it through ready for picking apart
my_url = "https://www.carehome.co.uk/care_search_results.cfm/searchunitary/Tower-Hamlets"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/lemonade/Documents/work/chromedriver')
driver.get(my_url)
page_s = soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')

#Finds relvant divs
containers = page_s.findAll("div", {"class": "home-name"})


for container in containers:
    name_container = container.p
    all_a = name_container.findAll("a")
    print(all_a)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[<a name="member_21310"></a>, <a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/20001005SILA" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:28px">Silk Court</a>]
[<a name="member_35665"></a>, <a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005FITA" style="">Westport Care Home</a>]
[<a name="member_34393"></a>, <a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/20001005ASPA" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:28px">Aspen Court Care Home</a>]
[<a name="member_4936"></a>, <a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005SYDA" style="">Beaumont Court</a>]
[<a name="member_40189"></a>, <a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/20001005HAWA" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:28px">Hawthorn Green Residential and Nursing Home</a>]
[<a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005COXA">
                                Coxley House
                            </a>]
[<a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/85852">
                                Toby Lodge
                            </a>]
[<a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005HOTA">
                                Hotel in the Park
                            </a>]
[<a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005RETB">
                                34/35 Huddleston Close
                            </a>]
[<a href="https://www.carehome.co.uk/carehome.cfm/searchazref/10001005APPA">
                                Approach Lodge
                            </a>]
```

Comment: Usage of selenium is overkill here as you can fetch the same content using requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using css selector `select()` which will returns expected output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver

#grabspage and parses it through ready for picking apart
my_url = "https://www.carehome.co.uk/care_search_results.cfm/searchunitary/Tower-Hamlets"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/lemonade/Documents/work/chromedriver')
driver.get(my_url)
page_s = soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')
containers = page_s.select("div.home-name>p>a[href]")

for container in containers:
    print(container.text.strip())
```

**Output**:

```
Silk Court
Westport Care Home
Aspen Court Care Home
Beaumont Court
Hawthorn Green Residential and Nursing Home
Coxley House
Toby Lodge
Hotel in the Park
34/35 Huddleston Close
Approach Lodge
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below solution :

driver.get("https://www.carehome.co.uk/care_search_results.cfm/searchunitary/Tower-Hamlets")

```
containers=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'home-name')]//p//a[@href]")))

for container in containers:
     print container.text
```

[image]